# Binding class method to event in google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, closures, google-maps-api-3

In V2 of the Google Maps API, you could bind map events to a class method using the GEvent.bind function:

```
GEvent.bind(this.drag_marker, "dragstart", this, this.start_dragging_route);
```

In the example above pretend that's a link from a prototype.init function, where `start_dragging_route` is a method inside the class.

It appears that the bind method doesn't exist anymore, at least not in the documentation.  If it's true I have one way to solve it, but it's a touch ugly so I'd love to hear some other solutions to this problem.

How can I implement the GEvent.bind function in Google Maps API V3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh right.  Closures.  Duh.

```
var self = this;
google.maps.event.addListener(this.drag_marker, "dragstart", function(latlng) {
    self.start_dragging_route(latlng);
});
```